# How do I handle hang from an ssh command from my bash script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh

I am working on a distributed Linux system.In my bash script I want to grep the output of :

```
ssh $ipaddress ibstat
```

The above command will hang if the machine is down. How do I handle the hang and come out of a the bash script with a non-zero value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeout` utility may be your choice for that:

```
timeout 5 ssh $ipaddress ibstat
```

will exit with non-zero result after 5 seconds, set it to a reasonable value sufficient for  ibstat to complete

Comment: I will try this and update. Thanks!!

Comment: There is a problem with timeout :  If the ssh is proper and I give an extra second for it to run, it will come out only after the timeout and will always return a non- zero value which should not be the case. Also if we wait the failed case will unnecessarily wait for those seconds.

Comment: There will be no extra waiting till the timeout expires if ssh remote command finishes normally before the timeout value. If remote command fails, it too will return immediately, not waiting till the end of timeout, and the exit code will be different from the exit code of timeout itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ConnectTimeOut` option with a low value, which you may need to adjust for your particular environment:

```
$ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $ipaddress
ssh: connect to host 192.168.123.123 port 22: Connection timed out
$ echo $?
255
```

You even get a return value which you can test - `255` means an error occurred processing the command.

Comment: Your ssh gives an error : **ssh: connect to host 192.168.123.123 port 22: Connection timed out** . Mine does not give an error, it just hangs.I have to press CTRL+C to come out of it.

Comment: Do you get any other message, such as `ssh: Ignoring unknown configuration option 'ConnectTimeout=2` ?  The above was tested on Debian and Alpine running `openssh` client.

Comment: No it does not. Mine is a SUSE .

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check host availability first:

```
if ping -c 1 $ipaddress &> /dev/null
then
  ssh $ipaddress ibstat
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: The ping works fine but the ssh hangs.

Comment: You wrote:
The above command will hang if the machine is **down**.
So, just use ping command for checking host is alive.

Try it: -o ServerAliveInterval=<secs>, for aborting connection

Comment: I will try this and update. Thanks!!